# Como remover aspas com AWK

Tags: awk

Olá
Estou tentando pegar a saída de ip do meu banco de dados no docker usando AWK pra automatizar meu ambiente, meu código tá assim

```bash
docker inspect api-maria-1 | grep IPAddress | awk '(NR > 2){print $2}'
```

e eu recebo a seguinte saída

```bash
"172.20.0.2",
```

não sou muito intimo do AWK ainda, gostaria de saber como posso remover as aspas e a vírgula no final

Se puder, favor explicar a solução apresentada
Isso me ajuda a entender melhor a linguagem
e ter mais noção do que estou implementando
vlw!

Comment: é por isso que não se utiliza o ip em automações do docker, deve-se utilizar o nome do serviço. Para evitar usar o `ip` visto que não existe garantia do ip que a instância vai subir. Talvez se tentasse explicar o que está tentando podemos sugerir uma melhor estratégia.

Comment: só estou tentando construir um ambiente de teste onde eu inicio um script.sh que faz o compose down e up da minha aplicação, mas também envia meu arquivo.sql pro banco de dados, só pra eu não precisar escrever SQL na linha de comando e sim no meu editor

Comment: seria o ```api-maria-1``` o nome do meu container, é sempre o mesmo nesse caso

Comment: já tentou utilizar o parâmetro -h do utilitário de linha de comando `mysql`?

Comment: passando como argumento do parâmetro -h o nome do serviço?

Comment: testei com ```mysql -h api-maria-1 -u root -p``` e eu recebo ```unkown mysql server host```

Comment: como está fazendo o binding das portas no arquivo docker-compose.yaml?

Comment: estou usando ```networks: back``` e ```ports: 3300:3306```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar:

```
docker inspect e9dd33dd0e48  | grep IPAddress |  tail -1 |  awk '1' RS="[^0-9.]+"
```

também é possível utilizar somente o comando docker, como:

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' e9dd33dd0e48
```

Comment: legal, funciona melhor pq o valor do ip na minha solução é fixo então já não rodava mais de uma vez pq o ip muda ao resetar o container kkk

Answer (score 2):

A função `substr()` do awk resolve o problema

O comando `NR > 2` informa que devem ser capturadas as linhas abaixo da segunda linha. Na saída original são 3 linhas onde só a terceira importa

`print` imprime na tela

`substr()` é uma função que recebe 3 parâmetros

- 1 Coluna **$2**
- 2 Caractere inicial **2**
- 3 Caractere final **10**

Dessa forma ele só vai imprimir na tela os caracteres de 2 a 10 da coluna 2

O código fica assim:

```bash
docker inspect api-maria-1 | grep IPAddress | awk '(NR > 2) {print substr($2,2,10)}'
```